# sql query to compare

Tags: sql, if-statement, conditional-statements

I want to show 'Pass' if marks of the student are 33 or above and 'Fail' if they are less than 33.

My table is `id,rollno,subject,marks` what i want to show is

record:

```
id rollno subject marks 
10 1253   english 67
```

desired output

```
id rollno subject  marks status
10 1253   english  67    Pass
11 1247   computer 24    Fail
```

plz tell me the query

Comment: What about when they score 33 exactly?

Comment: Either put the pass mark in a table and `JOIN` to that table OR use a `CASE` statement, depending on how likely the ranges are to change.

Answer (score 1):

for t-sql (MSSQL):

```
SELECT id, rollno, subject, marks,
       case when marks >=33 THEN 'Pass'
            else  'Fail'
       end [Status]
FROM <TABLE NAME>
```

Comment: Why the "for mysql" note? That only uses SQL92 ANSI that is compliant with all major RDBMS I know of, except the part of using [] around Status

Comment: +1 for the information @cyberwiki I haven't worked much with other RDBMSes.

Answer (score 0):

generic solution:

```
select id, rollno, sbject, marks, 'Pass' as status from table_name where marks >= 33
union
select id, rollno, sbject, marks, 'Fail' as status from table_name where marks < 33
```

Comment: Is such a table likely to be indexed on the marks column? This will scan the table twice if there is no index.

Comment: yes indexing marks column is a clever idea, specially if there is a huge amount of records.

Comment: depends if you want to get rid of repeating rows... however the two results would yield the same results so in that regard duplicates would only be removed from the two result sets individually

Answer (score 0):

This should work in Oracle db -

```
SELECT id,
  rollno,
  subject,
  mark,
  (
  CASE
    WHEN mark < 33
    THEN 'FAIL'
    ELSE 'PASS'
  END) status
FROM table_name;
```